wasmtime example doesn't run
I am currently exploring the add example for wasm component which is wasi-0.2, from   wasmtime component doc diligently following their example, unfortunately it doesn't run
#[allow(warnings)]
mod bindings;

use bindings::Guest;

struct Component;

impl Guest for Component {

    fn add(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
        x + y
    }
}

bindings::export!(Component with_types_in bindings);

lib.rs
package component:add;

/// An example world for the component to target.
world example {
    export add: func(x: s32, y: s32) -> s32;
}


world.wit
Wasmtime Version: wasmtime-cli 21.0.1 (cedf9aa0f 2024-05-22)
Steps to reproduce

cargo component build --release
cargo run --release -- 1 2 ../add/target/wasm32-wasi/release/add.wasm

Error
error: a bin target must be available for **cargo run**

It turns out, that the example specified a host was used to run the component, which uses wasmtime crates to generate Rust bindings.
